# Vueify / VueRouter / Laravel - Component not defined

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm building a relatively simple laravel application and wanted to learn Vue.js... which is turning into a super frustrating mess...

Anyway, here's the issue. No matter what I do, I get the error that my component isn't defined.

Here's what I have...

**Gulpfile**

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
  require('laravel-elixir-vueify');

// Elixir Mixins.
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.browserify('main.js');
});
```

**/resources/assets/js/main.js**

```
   var Vue =  require('vue');
   var VueRouter = require('vue-router');
   Vue.use(VueRouter);
   import Form2016_1099_misc from './components/2016-1099-misc.vue';
   Vue.component('Form2016_1099_misc', Form2016_1099_misc);
```

**In my blade file...**

```
@section('content')
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Hello App!</h1>
    <p>
      <!-- use v-link directive for navigation. -->
      <a v-link="{ path: '/recipient' }">Go to Recipient</a>
      <a v-link="{ path: '/form/2016/1099-misc' }">Go to 1099</a>
    </p>
    <!-- route outlet -->
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
@endsection

@section('footer')
  <script src="{{ asset('/js/main.js') }}"></script>

  <script>
    // Define some components
    var RecipientForm = Vue.extend({
      template: '<p>This is the recipient form.</p>'
    });
    var App = Vue.extend({});
    var router = new VueRouter();

    router.map({
      '/recipient': {
        component: RecipientForm
      },

      '/form/2016/1099-misc': {
        component: Form2016_1099_misc
      },
    });
    router.start(App, '#app');
  </script>
@endsection
```

**/resources/assets/js/components/2016-1099-misc.vue**

```
<template>
    {{ msg }}
</template>

<style>

</style>

<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                msg: 'This is a test'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I run gulp and it operates successfully. When I go to view the page in my browser, I get the error message

```
ReferenceError: Form2016_1099_misc is not defined
```

I'm certain that I'm doing a bunch of things wrong. I'm super new to Vue and I'm struggling with grasping it...

Update:

I have moved all the script code from my blade file into the main.js file and now main.js looks like this -

```
var Vue =  require('vue');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');
use(VueRouter);
import Form2016_1099_misc from './components/2016-1099-misc.vue';
Vue.component('Form2016_1099_misc', Form2016_1099_misc);

// Define some components
var RecipientForm = Vue.extend({
  template: '<p>This is the recipient form.</p>'
});

var App = Vue.extend({});
var router = new VueRouter();

router.map({
  '/recipient': {
    component: RecipientForm
  },

  '/form/2016/1099-misc': {
    component: Form2016_1099_misc
  },


});

router.start(App, '#app');
```

I now get the error message

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: link (found in component: <router-app>)
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the component with Vue. You are telling the router to build a component view when the route changes, but Vue also needs to know about the component.

After you import your component, try: 
`Vue.component('Form2016_1099_misc', Form2016_1099_misc);`

See: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Registration

Comment: I added the Vue.component('Form2016_1099_misc', Form2016_1099_misc); to my main.js file and ran Gulp again (updated the main post here too) and there's no change. When I load the page in the browser, I still get the same "Form2016_1099_misc is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

I was apparently loading Vue twice. Once from NPM and the other from the CDN. I removed the CDN and now it works fine...